# Picard–Lindelöf theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

My lecturer says that out of the area D (where differential equation meets the conditions of the  Picard–Lindelöf theorem) can't be any solutions for the differential equation, because 
there, he claims, the equation isn't  defined.
I don't understand why out of the area D the equation isn't defined. It only stops meeting the  Picard–Lindelöf theorem conditions, but it still could be defined and may have a solution(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the context. Usually in the statement of the theorems and for simplicity one considers the setup where $f$ (of $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$) is defined only on $D$ and satisfies the Lipschitz condition. Then the remark is valid.

In applications of the theorems one encounters situations where $f$ is defined on a bigger set $U$ and satisfies a specific Lipschitz condition on a smaller set $D$. Then one can of course try to continue a solution inside $D$ to the outside. For instance in the theory of maximal solutions or in the existence theorem for continuously differentiable $f$ (theorem of Cauchy).